# Whether PGP is send over MIME?

Tags: email, pgp

If I am using PGP to encrypt mails whther it is send as a MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) message, and S/MIME and PGP are used for providing email security.

When I send PGP message using a email client to my another web based account, what I got was a an attachment.

Comment: Can you explain why you care? As an old messaging admin, I'd like nothing better than to read a detailed explanation of the interoperation of MIME and PGP, liberally quoting RFC 2015, but I suspect you may have a specific practical problem behind this that you want answering.

Comment: @Graham Its just for academic point of view only. Was looking for differentiating the two. But though how they would act together when I employ PGP in my mail agent like thunderbird

Comment: to enable inline support `defaults write org.gpgtools.gpgmail UseOpenPGPInlineToSend -bool YES`

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of signing/encrypting email with PGP:
Inline-PGP and PGP/MIME.

Inline PGP takes a plain text message, and signs it or encrypts it, and the signed or encrypted message is sent as a single plain text message.

PGP/MIME uses a MIME-type of either multipart/signed (or for encrypted mails multipart/encrypted.)  The original unsigned message is left alone, and an additional MIME part is added which contains the signature. This would MIME part would be seen by any non-PGP-aware MUA as being just some random attachment.

The difference between PGP and S/MIME is more in the formatting of the certificates, and the trust model used. PGP uses a web-of-trust, and S/MIME uses a PKI based on Certification Authorities.  A PGP public key file is formatted very differently from an X.509 certificate.

In terms of mixing PGP and S/MIME, its possible to do, if you use inline-PGP, and then S/MIME sign the message.  (Why one would want to is another question.)

Answer (score 0):

MIME **convert** raw-binary data to the form, which can be transferred by e-mail.

PGP|S/MIME **encrypt** data, produced by MIME